# mod_rewrite with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, mod-rewrite

im using shared hosting. i build my web application with codeigniter and my new web directory will be as follows:

```
/home/projName/public_html/proj_v3/
```

under this dir, there are index.php, .htaccess. as shown above, i separated different project version in different directories (ie: proj_v1,proj_v2, proj_v3). the web applications allows photo upload and it's stored in **/home/projName/public_html/proj_v3/application/uploads**. **proj_v2** currently has the latest uploaded photo since it's still in use. because i have different version of projects, i want to place directory uploads in a common directory such as **/home/projName/public_html**. so that for any new version of projects, i won't have to move the upload folder to the new project folder. this might cause downtime.

currently, the .htaccess file in **/home/projName/public_html/proj_v2** is:

```
Options -indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1/ [L]
```

i have another .htaccess in **/home/projName/public_html/** is:

```
Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
Rewriterule ^(.*)\.*$  proj_v3/index.php/$1/
RewriteOptions MaxRedirects=3
```

basically how should i go about editing the 2nd **.htaccess** file in /home/projName/public_html/ so that if the web directory is **domain.com/uploads/image.png**, it  gets the image from **/home/projName/public_html/uploads**. currently, the 2nd **.htaccess** file tells **domain.com** to point **/home/projName/public_html/proj_v3**

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|gif|png|wmv|bmp)$ /uploads/$1
```

Might work for you. You can add other formats as needed.

Comment: hey tks. i added to my current rules and it looks like this: Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
Rewriterule ^(.*)\.*$  proj_v3/index.php/$1/
RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|gif|png|wmv|bmp)$ /uploads/$1
RewriteOptions MaxRedirects=3... but im not able to view the photos..

Comment: Try adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` as cchana posted to the .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is allow the paths to real files and folders to exist, while redirecting everything else to CodeIgniter, and you can achieve this using this in your second .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Definitely worth reading this article on the CodeIgniter website about [mod rewrite](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite)

I actually gave a similar answer before: [mod_rewrite in Users/<username>/Sites directory on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935894/mod-rewrite-in-users-username-sites-directory-on-osx/9939343#9939343)